# IOLoop.add_callback vs IOLoop.add_timeout in Tornado?

Tags: python, web, chat, tornado, long-polling

I'm using Tornado for my web chat and confusing between IOLoop.add_callback and IOLoop.add_timeout.

As I know IOLoop.add_timeout comes with a specific interval, and how about IOLoop.add_callback? does it have a fixed interval set by Tornado? or IOLoop.add_callback comes with no interval and is based on IO events?

I just can't find detailed information from Tornado documentation.
http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/ioloop.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [IOLoop's source code](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/ioloop.py) and the documentation, add_callback simply registers a callback function to be executed later, by appending it to a list. Then, on the next IOLoop iteration it calls every callback (in FIFO order). Add_callback must be called at the moment when you have something available, such as an I/O event. For more details, check this [article](http://golubenco.org/2009/09/19/understanding-the-code-inside-tornado-the-asynchronous-web-server-powering-friendfeed/).

Comment: i put add_timeout at the end of my long-poll handler function (the one with decorator @tornado.web.asynchronous), it works fine, however it isn't a true real-time handler. i replace add_timeout by add_callback, and the system hangs!

Comment: If you're doing long-polling somewhere, you must call add_timeout a few times to "catch" the event, as described in this example http://hymloth.posterous.com/bringing-celery-and-tornado-together